# Getting repeated values when I try to add a dictionary to an array in a loop

Tags: objective-c

This is my code for my test app where I want to show users on the next view controller but when I run and try to retrieve the values it is giving me repeated values. I have used `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSMutableArray`.

```
#import "DBManager.h"

static DBManager *sharedInstance = nil;
static sqlite3 *database = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;

@implementation DBManager

-(void) getsaveData:(NSString *)Username
{
    const char *dbpath = [newFileAtPath UTF8String];
    NSMutableArray *userArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSString *getSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME != \"%@\"",Username];
        const char *retrievestmt = [getSQL UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, retrievestmt, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)//in this while loop i am getting repeated values
            {
               NSString *User_ID = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                [userInfo setObject:User_ID forKey:@"ID"];
                //[userArray addObject:User_ID];

                NSString *User_Email = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                [userInfo setObject:User_Email forKey:@"Email"];
                //[userArray addObject:User_Email];

                NSString *Password = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                [userInfo setObject:Password forKey:@"Email"];
                //[userArray addObject:Password];

                NSString *User_name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                [userInfo setObject:User_name forKey:@"Username"];
                //[userArray addObject:User_name];

                NSString *User_Avatar = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
                [userInfo setObject:User_Avatar forKey:@"Avatar"];
                //[userArray addObject:User_Avatar];

                [userArray addObject:userInfo];
                NSLog(@"userArray %@",userArray);

            }
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

In the `while` loop I am geeting the error.

I tried multiple times with multiple solutions please help me fix this.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simple - you are incorrectly reusing the `userInfo` dictionary. You need to create a new instance in each loop iteration.

Move the line:

```
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

to just after the `while` loop line.

You also have many other issues with your code:

1. You never close the database.
2. You never finalize the prepared statement.
3. You needlessly reset the prepared statement.
4. You have insufficient error checking/logging.
5. You are not using standard naming conventions.
6. You are not using standard whitespacing which makes your code harder to read.
7. You don't use consistent curly brace placement. Pick a style and use it everywhere.
8. You are using static variables when you should not be.
9. Never build SQL statements using `stringWithFormat:`. Properly bind values to the query.
10. Never use `SELECT *` in a query. Explicitly list out the columns to ensure you get consistent and expected column values.

Here's is your code updated for these issues:

```
#import "DBManager.h"

static DBManager *sharedInstance = nil;

@implementation DBManager

- (void)getsaveData:(NSString *)username {
    const char *dbpath = [newFileAtPath UTF8String];
    NSMutableArray *userArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *retrievestmt = "SELECT USER_ID, USER_EMAIL, PASSWORD, USER_NAME, USER_AVATAR FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME != ?"; // replace * with actual column names
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, retrievestmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [username UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                NSString *userID = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                userInfo[@"ID"] = userID;

                NSString *userEmail = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                userInfo[@"Email"] = userEmail;

                NSString *password = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                userInfo[@"Password"] = password;

                NSString *username = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                userInfo[@"Username"] = username;

                NSString *userAvatar = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
                userInfo[@"Avatar"] = userAvatar;

                [userArray addObject:userInfo];
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);

            NSLog(@"userArray %@",userArray);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unable to prepare the statement at %s: %s", retrievestmt, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

        sqlite3_close(database);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to open the database at %@: %s", dbpath, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: 11. Never write SQL by hand.  Use FMDB or CoreData. ;)